# Generating timer events in the cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, stream-processing

I am trying to solve the problem of generating distributed timing events for my application on the amazon cloud:

A server gets a message. As a result the system has to do something within X minutes. My problem is that the system needs to potentially handle millions of messages per second during peak time. Also, during that time interval the server that got the message might crash. So I am looking for a distributed solution that can receive a message, and then fire another message with a guarantee several minutes later.

I could design a sharded system by myself, but I was hoping that some distributed streaming framework can do this easily. But what I found so far are ones that complete transactions immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat vague, but if you are looking for a fault-tolerant, geographically distributed way of processing messages, the you should take a look at AWS SQS or SQS in combination with SNS.

```
http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/
http://aws.amazon.com/sns/
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, it will not do. I am trying to get delayed events: (Do something in exactly 2 hours) .SQS seems to limit the amount of delayed messages to 120K messages per queue. This limit is too low for a large distributed system. It also limits the delay to 15 minutes. I have a serious problem here if I want the event to fire within an hour or a day.